# Getting strange characters from strncpy() function

Tags: c, arrays, string, c-strings

I am supposed to load a list of names from a file, and then find those names in the second file and load them in a structure with some other data (for the simplicity, I will load them to another array called "*test*".

**The first part** is just fine, I am opening a file and loading all the names into a 2dimensional array called *namesArr*.
**The second part** is where unexpected characters occur, and I can't understand why. Here is the code of the function:

```
void loadStructure(void){
    char line[MAX_PL_LENGTH], *found;
    int i, j=0;
    char test[20][20];

    FILE *plotPtr=fopen(PLOT_FILE_PATH, "r");
    if (plotPtr==NULL){perror("Error 05:\nError opening a file in loadStructure function. Check the file path"); exit(-5);}
    while(fgets(line, MAX_PL_LENGTH, plotPtr)!=NULL){                   // This will load each line from a file to an array "line" until it reaches the end of file.
        for(i=0; i<numOfNames; i++){                                    // Looping through the "namesArr" array, which contains the list of 20 character names.
            if((found=strstr(line, namesArr[i]))!=NULL){                // I use strstr() to find if any of those names appear in the particular line.
                printf("** %s", found);                                 // Used of debugging.
                strncpy(test[j], found, strlen(namesArr[i])); j++;      // Copying the newly found name to test[j] (copying only the name, by defining it's length, which is calculated by strlen function).
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(plotPtr);
    printf("%s\n", test[0]);
    printf("%s\n", test[1]);
    printf("%s\n", test[2]);
}
```

This is the output I get:

```
...20 names were loaded from the "../Les-Mis-Names-20.txt".
** Leblanc, casting
** Fabantou seems to me to be better," went on M. Leblanc, casting
** Jondrette woman, as she stood
Leblanct╕&q
Fabantou
Jondretteⁿ  └

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.005 s
Press any key to continue.
```

The question is, why am I getting characters like "╕&q" and "ⁿ  └" in the newly created array? And also, is there any other more efficient way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: you need to append null-terminator to the `test[j]` after strncpy

Comment: The length limitation for `strncpy` should be based on the target size, not the source length: that's the point of using it over `strcpy`, which uses only the source length.

Comment: for ease of understanding and readability by us humans: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement:*  2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a blank line.

Comment: the posted code seems to be missing the #define statement for : `MAX_PL_LENGTH`

Comment: `strncpy(test[j], found, strlen(namesArr[i]));` --> `strncpy(test[j], found, 19); test[j][19] = '\0';`

Comment: when posting a question about a runtime problem, you need to post code that cleanly compiles, is small, and still exhibits the problem.  The posted code does not compile

Comment: the function: `fgets()` will also input a newline.  which you probably do not want to save/display.   suggest in body of loop controlled by call to `fgets()` to insert the statements: `char *newline; if( (newline = strchr( line, '\n')  != NULL ) { *newline = '\0'; }`

Comment: @user3629249 it's a good point, but here the `strstr` usage will still find a substring anyway.

Comment: @user3629249 I didn't want to post the whole code as it also contains two external files, so it would be rather large. This way, the question is not too personal and someone else having the same question would be able to find the answer much easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `strncpy` does not store a null in the target array if the length specified is less than the source string (as is always the case here).  So whatever garbage happpend to be in the `test` array will remain there.

You can fix this specific problem by zeroing the `test` array, either when you declare it:

```
char test[20][20] = { { 0 } };
```

or as you use it:

```
memset(test[j], 0, 20);
strncpy(test[j], found, strlen(namesArr[i]));
```

but in general, it is best to avoid `strncpy` for this reason.

Comment: Unclear that `... strncpy(test[j], found, strlen(namesArr[i]));` insures a null character in `test[j]`.  Was that the intent?  Do not see that `strlen(namesArr[i]) < 20`

Comment: @chux: yes, must have strlen <= 19, since the fixed size dest only has that much space -- if it is longer, you overrun the buffer.  Yet another reason to avoid both strcpy and strncpy.

Comment: `strlen()` will always give <20, as `namesArr[i]` is also limited and does not contain strings larger than that. This solved the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The length limitation for `strncpy` should be based on the target size, not the source length: that's the point of using it over `strcpy`, which uses only the source length. In your code

```
strncpy(test[j], found, strlen(namesArr[i]));
```

the length parameter is from the source array, which defeats the purpose of using `strncpy`. In addition, the `nul` terminator will not be present if the function copies the full limit of bytes, so the code should be

```
strncpy(test[j], found, 19);        // limit to target size, leaving room for terminator
test[j][19] = '\0';                 // add terminator (if copy did not complete)
```

Whether you loaded `namesArr[]` from file correctly is another potential issue, since you do not show the code.

Comment: Agree.  Note: `strncpy(test[j], found, sizeof test[j] - 1);` would be more maintainable.

Comment: When a magic number (like 20) appears, better to have it only occur once and let the rest of code used derived/compute values.

Comment: @chux I would normally use say `#define STRSIZE 20` wherever it is not a run-time value.

Comment: I hard coded 20 as the program is designed to do specific task, and it won't ever need more than 19 characters.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I understand what you are saying about the wrong way I am using `strncpy()`. What would you suggest me to do in order to achieve the same thing?
`namesArr[0]` is *Leblanc*, `line` is *"Madame Fabantou seems to me to be better," went on M. Leblanc, casting\n*, `strstr()` finds the start of the word *"Leblanc"* in the `line` and now I want to copy only *"Leblanc"* to `test[i]`, not "Leblanc, casting" (ie. only 7 characters)

Comment: @Nicke011 in general, you should pass the size of of the *target* buffer to `strncpy`. There is no point passing the source string length, because the function won't have any safeguard - it is the same limit as the simpler `strcpy` would have anyway. The advantage of `strncpy` over `strcpy` is that it prevents buffer overrun - but only if you tell it the size of the target buffer. Maybe it happened to be the same, in which case it is "lucky" but in another project it won't be the same. The answer you accepted: is wrong.

Comment: I perfectly understand what you're saying and I agree. Can you advise me another method how to better achieve this task?
Once again, array `line` is *"Madame Fabantou seems to me to be better," went on M. Leblanc, casting\n*, `found` pointer is pointing to **L** in *"Leblanc"*. How can I copy *x* characters (in this case 7 because that happens to be the length of namesArr[i] (where "Leblanc" is stored)) to some other array. At this point I don't care how long it is, as long it's longer than 20 characters, because namesArr[i] is already limited to 20 characters. Do you understand my problem?

Comment: The copy will stop at and including the `'\0'` string terminator, unless there is not enough room in the target buffer. `strcpy` does not know this, and carries on until it reached the `'\0'`, but `strncpy` stops where you tell it to in the argument passed, or at the `'\0'`, which happens first.

Answer (score 2):

Edited:

Slight modification to a previous answer:

1) Since you are working with C strings, make sure (since `strncpy(...)` does not do it for you) that you null terminate the buffer.
2) When using `strncpy` the length argument should represent the target string byte capacity - 1 (space for null terminator), not the source string length.

```
...
int len = strlen(found)
memset(test[j], 0, 20);
strncpy(test[j], found, 19);//maximum length (19) matches array size 
                            //of target string -1 ( test[j] ).
if(len > 19) len = 19; //in case length of found is longer than the target string.
test[j][len+1] = 0;
...
```

Comment: Doesn't this defeat the advantage of using `strncpy` over `strcpy`? The target size does not appear anywhere.

Comment: @WeatherVane - Edited to address (at least what I think are) the issues you brought up.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Chris Dodd said,, quoted from `man strncpy`

> The **strncpy()** function is similar [to the **strcpy()** function], except that at most *n* bytes of src are copied. **Warning**: If there is no null byte among the first n bytes of src, the string placed in dest will not be null-terminated.

Since the size parameter in your `strncpy` call is the length of the string, this will *not* include the null byte at the end of the string and thus your destination string will not be null-terminated from this call.